# Recursively concatenate audio files in directory with audio files in another directory

Tags: audio, concatenation

In Windows 10, I'm looking for a cmd or .bat method to recursively concatenate/combine .wav audio files in one directory with .wav audio files in one or more other directories.

Something like a recursive version of:

```
copy /b C:/audio_1/.wav + C:/audio_2/.wav C:/audio_combined
```

It doesn't necessarily matter which `.wav` in `C:/audio_1/` gets combined with which `.wav` in `C:/audio_2/`, I just want to generate a bunch of combined files from each of the source directories.

Comment: Do you want the output of the "combined" file to be each file played in series, or a mix of the two files playing at the same time? I know of no such tools, but one could be readily made with a programming language that is set up to read and write the .wav headers. Simple concatenation would break the .wav expected format.

Comment: Combined in series. So, for input like "C:A/, C:B/, C:C/" and output directory "C:/ABC_cat"

Where the target directories contain the following dialog files (with script):

C:A/x.wav, script= "1"
C:A/y.wav, script= "2"
C:A/z.wav, script= "3"
C:B/x.wav, script= "X"
C:B/y.wav, script= "Y"
C:B/z.wav, script= "Z"
C:C/x.wav, script= "D"
C:C/y.wav, script= "U"
C:C/z.wav, script= "H"
The output should be:

C:/ABC_cat/ABC_cat_01.wav, script= "1 X D"
C:/ABC_cat/ABC_cat_02.wav, script= "2 Y U"
C:/ABC_cat/ABC_cat_03.wav, script= "3 X H"

Answer (score 0):

Combined in series.  So, for input like "C:A/, C:B/, C:C/" and output directory "C:/ABC_cat"

Where the target directories contain the following dialog files (with script):

- C:A/x.wav, script= "1"
- C:A/y.wav, script= "2"
- C:A/z.wav, script= "3"
- C:B/x.wav, script= "X"
- C:B/y.wav, script= "Y"
- C:B/z.wav, script= "Z"
- C:C/x.wav, script= "D"
- C:C/y.wav, script= "U"
- C:C/z.wav, script= "H"

The output should be:

- C:/ABC_cat/ABC_cat_01.wav, script= "1 X D"
- C:/ABC_cat/ABC_cat_02.wav, script= "2 Y U"
- C:/ABC_cat/ABC_cat_03.wav, script= "3 X H"

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to be added as a comment in reply to the question asked above, not as a solution